# JS Bundling causing loading spinner issues in IE11 checkout - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, internet-explorer, jsbundling

Have tried to use Magento 2's JS bundling and am running into a strange error on IE 11 only. When proceeding to the checkout the loading spinner will not disappear. The page seems to load correctly in the background, but spinner just sticks.

We have removed all checkout javascript from the js bundling and the issue persists.

We do get a strange static.js console error, this might be related?

[image: static.js console error]

The syntax error it is referring to is this:
[image: static.js console error]

Any help would be hugely appreciated! As mentioned if we turn off JS Bundling the issue disappears.

Thanks